# No proprietary Nvidia driver available on Lenovo W550s

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04

I have a Lenovo W550s which contains a 3D Nvidia graphics chip, and I run Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit on it.

The "Additional Drivers" dialog only shows some processor microcode firmware but does not offer a proprietary driver for the Nvidia graphics chip.

lspci reports: 
"3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 137a (rev a2)"

Is there a way to use the proper driver for full 3D support without resort to hacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

This will install the nvidia-346 driver from official Ubuntu repositories. This driver supports your adapter. It is a long-term-support driver. It should get updates.

There is nothing fundamentally wrong if you install an Nvidia driver from ppa. It is an unofficial personal repository and a short time supported 355 driver. It may work better or not for you.

You can test both drivers.

Comment: Thank you! - Can you please comment on what exactly this does and why it is not offered in the proprietary drivers dialog? Also, how does this differ from hg8's method which suggests to install nvidia-355 from a ppa? And what does nvidia-prime do? 
If something goes wrong after installing this, will just purging those packages restore the current configuration again?
Sorry for being so curious, but I have in the past followed instructions just to find out that things got even worse so I would like to understand what I am doing! :)

Comment: I added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Lenovo website](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/w-series/w550s/), your graphic card is a NVIDIA Quadro K620M.

You can install the Nvidia driver using the following PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```

Comment: There is no need to add ppa.

Comment: Why that ? The new version is only in the PPA and contain a lot of fixes...

Comment: What "a lot of fixes" are there that are not added to LTS 346?

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/90393/en-us

Comment: These are fixes to of bugs in 355 drivers. There is no evidence that these bugs were in 346. But it is an option to install 355.

Comment: Thank you - could you please explain why this driver or an earlier version is not offered automatically in the proprietary drivers dialog? 
If anything goes wrong by doing this, how can I undo it again?